# How to assign generic parent type to a generic subtype

Tags: angular, typescript

This is more of a typescript question than angular. But let me explain the situation. I am using angular to pass data from a parent-to-child component. The parent has the following property.

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
    dataService: IService<ScrappedTypes>
}
```

Where `ScrappedTypes` is equal to.

```
type ScrappedTypes = ScrappedType1 | ScrappedType2 | ScrappedType3
```

and `IService` is equal to.

```
interface IService<T>{
  data: T;
}
```

Each individual `ScrappedType i.e 1,2,3` are different `interfaces` themselves.

I've 3 different `child components` in angular. Each representing a ScrappedType. So for example in my child components, I write the following.

```
export class ScrappedType1Component implements OnInit {
    dataService: IService<ScrappedType1>
}

export class ScrappedType2Component implements OnInit {
    dataService: IService<ScrappedType2>
}

export class ScrappedType3Component implements OnInit {
    dataService: IService<ScrappedType3>
}
```

But I get the following error.

```
Type 'IService<ScrappedTypes>' is not assignable to type 'IService<ScrappedType1>'

Type 'IService<ScrappedTypes>' is not assignable to type 'IService<ScrappedType2>'

Type 'IService<ScrappedTypes>' is not assignable to type 'IService<ScrappedType3>'
```

The goal is to `narrow` down the `ScrappedTypes` to one of the ScrappedType to be able to access the properties of each `ScrappedTypes` easily. How can this be accomplished in the correct way?

**[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u2bg2m?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

The most important error to resolve inside the stackblitz is `Type 'IService<ScrappedTypes>' is not assignable to type 'IService<ScrappedType1>'`. Ignore the other ones.

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/W44QKW), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: @jcalz The stackblitz for the problem 

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u2bg2m?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: This issue seems to be tied up with angular which I don't know very well; maybe someone who does can answer; I can see the TypeScript problem: your `AppComponent` is not a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), so the compiler cannot narrow its type based on checking `switchValue`. TS can't declare that a `class` is a discriminated union, although you can simulate this behavior.  But it looks like angular [has a limitation](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34522) that would stop you anyway.  So ‍♂️.

Comment: The closest I can think of doing is using a [discriminated-union-workaround from angular/angular#34522](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34522#issuecomment-650075628)... like [this forked version of your stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r6nttd?file=src/app/app.component.html).  If that works for you I could maybe write up an answer.  If not, then maybe something better will come along.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the problem is with your union type.

`type ScrappedTypes = ScrappedType1 | ScrappedType2 | ScrappedType3`

I think what typescript is telling you is that if you type one of your services then it needs to be type like the union `ScrappedType1 | ScrappedType2 | ScrappedType3` not just one of them. Probably not explaining it well enough.

Comment: Hi Richard. I know the error but I am asking the right way to approach this. What is the right way to do this